# Eigenvalues and singular values of $3 \times 3$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, singular-values

I'm asked to provide an example or disprove the existence of a $3\times 3$ matrix whose eigenvalues are all $0$ but has singular values $1$, $1/2$, $0$. My initial instinct was to consider the possible Jordan canonical forms of such a $3\times 3$ but I'm unsure if this is the best approach.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. You should provide more detail about your initial approach to the problem -- what you think works, what doesn't, and where you're stuck. As currently stated your question is likely to be poorly received, but that can be rectified by describing what you've done in more detail.

Comment: See the definition of singular values

Comment: Hey @sf23, how are you ? What have you tried so far ?

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist “My initial instinct was to consider the possible Jordan canonical forms of such a $3\times3$ . . .”

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor "...should provide more detail..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $$T = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \frac12 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

We have $T^*T = \operatorname{diag}\left(0, 1, \frac14\right)$ so the singular values of $T$ are $\left\{0, 1, \frac12\right\}$.

---

Also note that looking at the Jordan form is not sufficient because matrices in general are not unitarily similar to their Jordan forms. Meaning if a matrix $T$ has Jordan form $J$, then $T^*T$ may not have the same eigenvalues as $J^*J$.

What you could do is take a look at [Schur decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition) to conclude that every matrix is unitarily similar to an upper-triangular matrix. Then you could have taken $$T = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & a & b \\ 0 & 0 & c \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

and calculated its singular values.